# Does the "SQL_NO_CACHE" directive prevent a query from using the cache, or just from adding to it?

Tags: mysql, caching

The manual indicates that "SQL_NO_CACHE" prevents a query from being **added** to the cache. But it doesn't say anything about using the cache, that I can see.

I'm trying to benchmark two versions of a query, but they've already been run without "SQL_NO_CACHE". So I don't know if my tests are using the query cache or not.

Does the "SQL_NO_CACHE" directive prevent a query from using the cache, or just from adding to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MySQL query cache is indexed based on the full, literal text of the query, so there is functionally no difference: even if the directive were ignored, the results of a query with `SQL_NO_CACHE` would be stored in a different cache "slot" from the query without `SQL_NO_CACHE`. (Indeed, simply adding a space to the query somewhere, or changing "SELECT" to "select" -- for instance -- would also "bust" the query cache, making it run again. The MySQL query cache is not particularly sophisticated.)

That being said, a quick test by running a query with `SQL_NO_CACHE` and watching the `QCACHE_QUERIES_IN_CACHE` status confirms that `SQL_NO_CACHE` does prevent variables from being stored in the cache, and a look at [the source](https://github.com/twitter/mysql/blob/master/sql/sql_cache.cc#L1499) makes it look as though the presence of `SQL_NO_CACHE` will also keep MySQL from checking the cache for results.